# Best way to wire multiple laser modules

Tags: batteries, parallel, laser

I have purchased 16 Red 3-5V 650nm 5mW laser modules which I believe have a driver included.  I also have a 100000mAh Li-Polymer battery with 2 USB outputs, one at 5v 1A and one at 5v 2A.
If I wire the laser modules in parallel, should this work as the voltage would be 5v across them all?  If so, how many laser modules in parallel could the battery support?  Do I need anything else in the circuit?

Link for the laser modules is http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Industrial-linear-Red-Line-3-5V-650nm-5mW-Module-Focusable-Adjustable-Laser-Head/191968924976?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Answer (score 1):

This laser has a driver included, as the datasheet only gives a voltage rating for the supply (3-5V).

The laser is given at 5mW, but this is the optical power output.

To know if you can wire those laser to your battery, you need to know the power consumption of the laser, and it seems it is not given by the seller.

Thereof, you should measure the current yourself, just connect one laser to the battery with an Amp meter in serie.

Then you simply need to multiply the current by the amount of laser and see if it will be supported by your battery output.